# Dynamic textboxes value retrieval

Tags: php, dynamic, textbox

i had dynamically created textboxes.two things are constant in all these texboxes -'class=data_textboxes','name=text_[name of textbox as per database value]'.

these textboxes are in a form and when i submit how can i access all those textboxes values either one by one or get all of them in an array.i need to do server validation on these values using php.

secondly i want to send these values to database,how can i the values to database(corresponding to its database value)

let me explain 2nd scenario wid n xample. suppose database company value is ="yahoo" then its corresponding textbox name will be name="text_yahoo" and there are lots of other companies..so how to send values of text_yahoo textbox to database referencing to yahoo??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
  if(substr($key, 0, 5) == 'text_')
  {
    $fieldname = substr($key, 5);
    $fieldvalue = $value;
    .... add to database ....
  }
}
```

Basically the idea is to look at field names and if they start with certain text then it's the field you're looking for.